# Dotnet Setup project - Change user installation preferences from Code

Tags: c#, setup-project, user-permissions

I got an issue in which when we try to install the set up project in dot net ,a window will appear  like the one given below.

[image]

When we install this set up, I had done some code snippet to display the name of the User who had logged in to the system currently, based on the above selection.

```
public override void Commit(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);
        string appPath = Context.Parameters["AssemblyPath"].ToString();                       

        #region Automatically Launch Application After Install
        try
        {
            // Sending the value 2, repersenting it is from the pvMonitor.msi
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appPath);
        }
        catch { }
        #endregion
    }
```

When I select ‘ just me’ radio button the name of the current user is  getting displayed and when I select every one radio button, the System name is getting Displayed like the screen shot given below.

[image]

My requirement is that even if we select the EVERY ONE radio button, the current logged in User’s name should be get displayed  but with the same functionality of every one ,Since I don’t want  every user to install this set up when he logs in, ie this set up should be installed in a system once  .Plz suggest some Ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You may get the current user name using `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`.
Then, display the `name`(even if the user selected 'Every One')